# How to ask location permission in react native.60?

Tags: reactjs, native, android-permissions

I also added
Fine.Location permission to line in minifest.Xml file but nothing happen. My targetsdkverion =28. 
Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use  [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) and get permissions according to platform. On android you need to request permission on your own like bellow:

```
if (Platform.OS !=='android' )   
    Geolocation.requestAuthorization()
else {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                title: 'we need GPS location service',
                message:
                'we need location service to provide your location',
                // buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                buttonPositive: 'OK',
            },
        )
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        } else {
            Defaults.modal.current.renderModel(modalOptions);
            return false;
        }
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
}
```